# Thread, while loop and a System.out.print statement

Tags: java

Hi guys I have a nested Thread and using it to see when a player has taken a turn (in a draughts game) O have a game object and a public variable changedTurns.

```
new Thread() {
     public void run(){
         check();
     }
 private void check(){
      boolean sent = false;
      while(true){
      System.out.println("ee");             \\line 9
       if(game.changedTurns){
           System.out.println("gg");
            if(!sent){
                System.out.println("ok");
                sent =true;
             }
       }
   }
}.start();
```

Everything works as expected like above I.e console shows plenty of "ee" followed by "gg" and then "ok" when the player takes their turn, however without line 9 nothing is shown when the player takes their turn ?!

Comment: Try to print the value of game.changedTurns . If nothing is getting printed that means it is false.

Comment: Is the `changedTurns` field declared [`volatile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4)?  If not, the thread is [permitted by the Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) to optimize execution by examining the value of changedTurns only once.

Comment: Printing to stdout takes some amount of time, when you remove that line what may be happening is the `while(true)` loop is constantly iterating through, which may prevent the other thread from ever getting to do whatever it does that triggers `game.changedTurns`.

You should be able to replace the print statement with a (short) sleep and have it work as desired. However, it would be *much* better to refactor the code to be event driven instead of an infinite loop constantly checking something.

Comment: Like I say I try it with line 9 I make a game as normal, take a turn and it prints 'gg' and'ok' , I comment out line 9 run the exact same procedure, create a game and take a turn and nothing gets printed out.  As long as line 9 is there it 'a all fine , when I print game.changedTurns in line 9. It also works as expected -prints false then prints true when I take a turn, I remove line 9 same bug

Comment: VGR was right , changed to volatile and now works.

Comment: @Exupery I agree but I still wanted to find out what was happening here anyway

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use threading to analyze whether the player has taken a turn.  Just create a Player[] array and add a variable turn for the index of the player whose turn it is.  Increment turn when a Player makes a turn.